# What is the difference between this two:"new BigInteger()" and "Biginteger.valueOf()"?

Tags: biginteger

the "new BigInteger()" faster more than "Biginteger.valueOf()" ?
Please give me some advice

Comment: They do different things, so they are not comparable from a performance perspective.  The differences are all in what they create the object from.  The `valueOf` creates an object from a `long`.  The constructors create one from ... other things.  See the javadocs.

Comment: Docs show the "BigInteger(String val)" should character-to-digit mapping,but the "BigInteger valueOf(long val)" just Returns a BigInteger whose value is equal to that of the specified long,so does the latter perform better than the former?

Comment: If you want to convert a `long` to a `BigInteger` `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` is the fastest way to do it.  But if you want to convert a `String` to a `BigInteger`, then `new BigInteger(String)` is fastest.  Rather than asking vague questions, ask a clear specific question.  Faster **doing what**??

Comment: If you want some general advice: 1) Don't obsess over performance. For most applications, the performance differences you are asking about here won't make any difference. 2) Don't optimize prematurely.  3)  Don't optimize your code unless you need to.  4) When you do optimize your code, do it scientifically; i.e. based on actual evidence, not on guesswork or random facts / factoids you read on the internet. Benchmark the application, profile it, optimize it, repeat ... until you have reached your performance goal.  Then stop.

Comment: I learned it, thank you so much!